# Geopandas: buffer with vector in 3D

Tags: python, buffer, coordinates, geopandas, ogc

I have a problem with geopandas library.

I have a Linestring Geoseries with z coordinates that contains some WKT like:

> LINESTRING Z (420572.2735498088 6431128.402213755 56.53999986648559, 420324.4944151817 6431220.058498786 3.75)

I have tried to buffer this with:

`myGeoseries.buffer(2.5)`

But that give me:

> 'POLYGON ((420323.6270760528 6431217.71377645, 420323.4014295494 6431217.810081029, 420323.1863090952 6431217.928039102, 420322.9837864178........)

As you can see, with the buffer method, we loose the Z coordinates. I have searched in the fiona and geopandas documentation. I would want to know if I have missed something and if it's possible to buffer the X, Y and also the Z coordinates thanks to a method or a function in ogr, gdal package...

Comment: Do not expect 3D geometry from a 2D application.

Comment: So, is there a package that allows to work with 3D geometry?